# Adding an animated transition to a third party jquery plugin - Dropit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, animation

this is my first post here, I hope I too can contribute to something important someday :)

So.. I added a thid party jquery plugin to a site I am working on, the plugin can be found here http://dev7studios.com/dropit/

My question is, how can I add a simple transition to the hidden dropdown list so it can smoothly push down the content of the website? I added jQuery UI core, but the ('class', 1000) doesnt seem to apply to the *.js of the plugin..

Thank you all very much in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Welcome. It would be helpful to update the question with some sample code of what you have tried. That would give context to what you mean by `('class', 1000)`.

Comment: I am referring to the source of the plugin's *.js file where the classes are being added for a onClick event. 

The solution below worked just fine for me, anyways thank you too for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow :)

I downloaded the plugin and their code is pretty well formatted and commented.

If you go to lines 28 and 40 of dropit.js you will see that there is the code to "show" and "hide" the dropdown. Note that they are using the "hide()" and "show()" so you can go ahead and change it to animations/effects you like.

For example on line 36 you will find:

```
$(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).addClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).show();
```

You can go an change that, for example, to something like this:

```
$(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).addClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).fadeIn();
```

Pretty simple, right? So basically you will be chaning (in the .js) the "hide()" and "show()" transitions to some transitions you want to use.

EDIT:
BTW, here are some effects/transitions you can use with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: Thank you very much, Jhuliano! That was quick.

Comment: BTW, I would suggest (if you have the time and skill to do it) that you parametrize the animations and then send a pull request to the author ;)! I'm pretty sure the community and author of the plugin will appreciate it.

Comment: Whenever I get the needed skills to do so.. For now I just adjust things :) 

But either way, the plugin states - a super simple dropdown.